# Administration interface for REST api

Tags: php, mysql, api, database-administration, admin-interface

I made several apps for myself, with simple REST api's, and when I needed to blacklist a user, or something else "administrator-like-actions", I just do it directly in the MySQL database.

Now I'm working on a project for a client, who wants an administration interface, where he can do these kinds of actions.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I'm sure that I can build on top of an existing piece of software, but I can't find anything. I might be searching with the wrong keywords.

I think October CMS, could do the trick for me, but I am not sure yet... :-)

Comment: any feedback on this? Was looking at wordpress and their WP REST API plugin but seems immature at the moment

Comment: No, I didn't get any response on it, and I ended up making my own. Can't understand that there isn't a system available or a boilerplate of some sort. Thousands of people have made this before me.